# Dropped wireless on Android?

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues

I currently have a Droid Incredible (Froyo with ROM: Skyraider 3.5 w/ Sense)

For a while now, my wireless connection on my Droid Inc just drops and switches over to 3G  even though wireless, on both the router and phone, are still on. All my other devices connected wirelessly are still connected and functioning. I had this problem on pre and post rooting and ROMing.

What could be the root cause of this?  Has any other Android smartphone experienced this?

Is there a feature/app that could warn you that your wireless has dropped and is switching over to mobile network and vise versa.  I only ask because the switch over either way is seamless and can be annoying when browsing or downloading apps.

Comment: Have you tried on multiple WiFi networks?  It could be your router if not.

Comment: This happens to my Moto Flipside all the time! The only hack I could find was this app that made it easier to toggle the wifi on and off: http://www.appbrain.com/app/wi-fi-status-bar-switch/com.friedflow.statusswitch (and FWIW it happens on wifi at home, work, and pretty much everywhere else I've used wifi, and it doesn't happen on the wife's iPhone or our laptops)

Comment: To add to Matthew's suggestion - are any other devices connected to the router having the same issue?

Comment: @travis - Is your Flipside running Skyraider or Sense?  Could one of these things be the common factor between both of your problems?

Comment: @JonnyP I'm not sure what either of those are, so I'll guess no.

Comment: @travis - Unless I'm mistaken Skyraider is a custom ROM that uses Sense UI (Sense UI was developed by HTC).  Since you have a Motorola phone the only way you'd be running Sense UI is if you flashed a custom ROM, whether that would be Skyraider or another that includes Sense.

Comment: @Matthew - Yes this does happen on other WiFi networks, though it is more noticeable on mine since I'm on my network most of the time

Comment: @JonnyP ah gotcha, then my answer is a definitive no then. :-) No custom ROMs support the Flipside (yet... that I know of).

Comment: @Daniel - All my other devices are fine when the WiFi drops on my phone.  I've been online on my laptop when my phone dropped the wireless, and my gf's touch iPod has never dropped its wireless

Answer (score 3):

After reading a bit this seems to be a pretty common issue with folks who are running Skyraider on their devices.  I don't know exactly what they're talking about, but apparently your radio needs to be the right version in order for your WiFi to act properly.  [This thread](http://www.incredibleforum.com/forum/htc-incredible-hacks/4162-updating-radio-after-root-skyraider-2-5-2-install.html) over at IncredibleForum looks like it might be where you need to start.

Comment: Thx JonnyP! I'll check this out, give it try and if it works I'll accept your answer :)

Comment: @A.Donahue - How's it going?  I've been a little curious about this radio thing ever since I read your question and have been thinking of looking into what my phone uses.

Comment: @A. Donahue - Still no dice?